# Sliding expiration for SSO-timeout/session

Tags: curity

Is it possible to enable sliding expiration for SSO-timeout/session in Curity so for every refresh of AccessToken (using RefreshToken) SSO-timeout will be renewed with "new max sso-time limit"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in the Curity Identity Server. Mainly because these are quite separate concepts — the refresh token and the SSO session. SSO is tied to a user and a session in the browser. The concept of access and refresh tokens is not limited to just the user operating an app. Very often these tokens will be used by OAuth clients independently from the user's browser (or even the user herself, e.g., it might be a backend process that needs access to the user's resources).

Comment: Yes but it feels like a large puzzle piece is missing in given SSO-journey. User experience will be very bad if you only have absolute expire time for SSO and cant renew it. Is this the way Identity Servers generally is working or just a feature that Curity is missing?

Comment: You can set a long expiration time for the SSO session (e.g. 30 days), then set a shorter time for "expire SSO session after inactivity period". Users that visit your app frequently will have their session valid for 30 days, while inactive users will have to log in again.